# How to access the Keyboard in an Eclipse RCP / LWJGL app?

Tags: keyboard, eclipse-rcp, lwjgl

I am working my way through the NeHe OpenGL examples, using the LWJGL for the OpenGL binding inside an Eclipse RCP application.

My OpenGL graphics are displayed inside the RCP canvas, not in a separate window.

Lesson 07 shows how to use the keyboard. If I try to do a:

```
Keyboard.create();
```

I get an error that the (OpenGL) "Display" has not been created.

If I create an OpenGL "Display" with org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(), then I get a new Window.

So how do I access the Keyboard *without* creating a new Window?

Comment: Well, if anyone cares, it goes like this: "glcanvas = new GLCanvas(...); glcanvas.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {...});"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the Keyboard without a Display, because of how LWJGL works behind the scenes. The best way is to just use AWT events. You can write your own input class, that could go something like this.

```
public class Input implements KeyListener {
    private boolean aDown; //is the A key down?
    //Ect, for all needed keys
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        switch (ke.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_A: aDown = true; break;
            //and so on for all other needed keys.
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        switch (ke.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_A: aDown = false; break;
            //and so on for all other needed keys.
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {} //Do nothing

    public void isADown() {return aDown;}

}
```

Comment: Well, that's what I did, as I already said in my comment. But thanks anyway.